# Why was "Booting New compiled kernel on Beaglebone Black via usb to ttl (serially)" closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons

Why was https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32149407/booting-new-compiled-kernel-on-beaglebone-black-via-usb-to-ttl-serially closed?

The question is (unusually) detailed and asks for a specific answer for how to perform a specific programming-related task. Yet is has been put on hold (and downvoted) without comment.

Now, the question is related to (but not a duplicate of) [u-boot flash emmc ttl serial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28042023/u-boot-flash-emmc-ttl-serial/28053750#28053750), and one of the answers to [Starter kit for bare-metal programming for Beaglebone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28165244/starter-kit-for-bare-metal-programming-for-beaglebone/28183249#28183249) contains a useful answer that also applies to this question, but neither is trivially found by searching if one does not already know the answer.

Comment: He describes a task, completely failed to actually ask a question.

Comment: Yes, a fair reason for a grammatical edit. He does however describe precisely what it is he wants to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

What's the actual question being posed here, though?

I'm not a person that's well-versed in the subject matter at all, yet I can't tell what the actual question is being asked.

Here's the crux of the question:

> I want to transfer the Image via the USB to TTL converter pl2303 ttl from my host to Beaglebone black. I also want to Boot the new kernel using Uboot bootloader.

If we ignore everything else about it - including the steps that they took - this is what we're left with.  They want to accomplish a task.

That's *fantastic*.  But it's not a question.  It doesn't convey what they're struggling with, what they've attempted, or anything like that - it's a "I want to do X" style question.

Looks like it was closed for the right reasons here.  The hope now is that the OP will come back to edit/clarify their question so that someone that is well versed in this can help them more directly.

Comment: The actual question asked is "how do I load my self-compiled Linux kernel over my serial connection to the target" (as opposed to fiddling with a microSD card every time). A common question for embedded targets that would be useful to have an easily findable answer for on SO.

I would be highly surprised if an inexperienced SO user having a clear question and having it closed with no other information than "unclear what you're asking" would bother coming back.

Comment: If that's the question, why didn't they ask it?  A clear and concise description of the problem would go a long way to helping someone not versed in this understand what the actual issue is; if nothing else but to pass it by as, "Someone with expertise could answer this."  It would certainly have appeased *me*.